# Extjs: share data between two functions

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a property in my controller which I need to change its value in one method and access the updated value in another function. How can I do this?

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
     config:{
        Var : 'Test',
        },
    method1:function(){
        var me = this;
        var str1 = me.getVar();
        //change str1 here to Test2
    },
    method2:function(){
        var me = this;
        var str2 = me.getVar();
        //get updated value here (Test2)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your property is defined via `config`, getter and setter methods are already generated automatically, i.e. in `method1` you can just call the setter to change the value:

```
method1: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.setVar('Test2');
},
```

Also refer to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-config), as this very basic case is covered there.